# Possible in Aurelia to wait for a promise in a custom element to complete before execution continues?

Tags: aurelia

If you have an Aurelia application where you have eg. a "language switcher" custom element in the navigation bar. Suppose these languages is to be fetched from a database call and returned via a promise.

The way I've implemented it right now is with a fetch call in the bind() function in my custom element, which returns a promise, but my problem is... what if this database request take a few seconds to complete - ideally I would not want the rest of my application to run before this promise is returned, since a lot of other elements depends on a language id from the language-switcher custom element.

What I need is to be able to guarantee that once the application reaches to custom element, "language switcher", in my navbar, it needs to block/pause/wait for the database fetch call to return and resolve it's promise, before moving ahead procession the application.

Comment: you can return the promise in the `activate` method of your route view-model. In this way, the app will wait for the promise. Router's views can wait for promises to be rendered but not custom elements

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Multiple other custom elements depends on this language-switcher custom element to have it's dropdown populated with languages and bound. So I need some way to pause further executing of the application until that promise is returned and resolved.

Comment: the `activate()` lifecycle hook is what you are looking for. Just be aware that you cannot use it in custom elements, only in views attached by the router

Comment: How do you bind the language Id to the other components? Is it possible to just handle a null value gracefully? For example in the view, throw an if.bind="languageId" on the elements that you want to avoid rendering. And in the view model, whether you have a subscription to the id or a property changed event, only do processing if a value exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `activate()` hook of your route view-model. For instance:

screen-1.js

```
export class Screen1 {

   activate() {
     //database call
     return myPromise
       .then(result => this.result = result);
   }
}
```

screen-1.html

```
<template>
   <require from="./language-switcher"></require>

   <language-switcher some-property.bind="result"></language-switcher>
</template>
```

For more information, read http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This is indeed exactly what I was hoping for - works like a charm! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This discussion might shed some light on the issue too https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/367

OP said: "Ideally, I would like to be able to implement a hook for the created() callback, return a promise, and have Aurelia wait for it to resolve before invoking the attached() callback..."

EisenbergEffect replied: "We can't provide this across all components. It would be a disaster for performance and would no longer map in any way to web components."

There was a workaround mentioned:

```
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import { CompositionTransaction } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class YearToDateGauge {
  static inject = [HttpClient, CompositionTransaction];
  constructor(http, compositionTransaction) {
  this.http = http;
  // https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/367
  this.compositionTransactionNotifier = compositionTransaction.enlist();
}

created() {
  // retrieve the data
  this.http.fetch('/books/')
      .then(data => {
          this.books = data; // store locally
          // done loading data, allow the attached() hook to fire
          this.compositionTransactionNotifier.done();
      return data;
  });
}

// fires only after `compositionTransactionNotifier.done()` is called
attached() {
// update the DOM here, e.g. draw a chart, etc
this.numBooks = this.books.length; // the user is guaranteed that    
  this.books will be availaible
}
}
```